# Scala Best Practice - What's the best way to add derived attributed to a source managed final case class

Tags: scala, case-class

Using protocol-buffers and scalapb, I have a number of source managed final case classes that are now immutable.

I need to be able to add additional derived attributes that can be referred to in subsequent methods.

For example, I'll have scalapb creating me a case class like this - and this cannot be edited as its source managed.

```
final case class rawData (x: int, y: string){}
```

I now want to have derived fields available. Because the case class is marked as final it cannot be extended, nor can I use implicit class.

I'm currently using this approach:

```
case class rawDataDerived (raw:rawData){
val isXOne:boolean = raw.x==1
}
```

I can now have

```
val testRaw = rawData(1,"Test")
val testRawWithDerivations = rawDataDerived(rawData)
testRawWithDerivations.isXone // returns true as expected.
```

This approach works, but is it the best approach?

Comment: Why can't you use an implicit class? It seems fitting for this case

Comment: @alexv - For some reason I thought I'd tried that and it didn't work, but then tried again this morning and it does work! But yes, agreed, an implicit class is defintely what I'm after - thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add data members then you will need to use containment as you do in the `RawDataDerived` class.

If you just want to add extension methods then an `implicit class` will work:

```
final case class RawData(x: Int, y: String)

implicit class RawDataOps(raw: RawData) {
  def isXOne = raw.x == 1;
}

println(RawData(0, "").isXOne) // false
println(RawData(1, "").isXOne) // true
```